# android radiobutton check after clearing check issue

Tags: android, radio-button

friends. I'm having a really silly problem with radiogroup. Yet I'm unable to find solution.

I will try to describe how to reproduce my problem:
I have radiobutton group and two buttons inside.
I select one of them, lets say 1st one.
Then I'm clearing selection by calling *radioGroup.clearCheck()*
After I'm trying to select 1st button, but its not checking.
If I check 2nd, it checks normally.
If I check 1st after checking 2nd it also works normally.

This may sound crazy, yet I can't fix it. Please help me, thanks in advance.

I use

```
@Override
protected void init() {
    View view = View
            .inflate(getContext(), R.layout.wo_task_yn_result, null);

    performed = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.yn_yes);
    notPerformed = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.yn_no);

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.yn_options);

    performed.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView,
                final boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(YES, "verify");
            if (isChecked) {
                Log.d(YES, "checked");
                result = YES;
            }
        }
    });

    notPerformed.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView,
                final boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d(NO, "verify");
            if (isChecked) {
                Log.d(NO, "checked");
                result = NO;
            }
        }
    });

    addView(view);
}
```

To create buttons and

```
@Override
public void clear() {
    radioGroup.clearCheck();

    result = "";
}
```

for clearing them

Comment: it would be best if you show thde code for the buttons

Comment: Ok, I've updated my questions. Hope this code is enough.

Comment: post it for the SO community.

Comment: Well not to humble, when i said, I've found solution, it just stupid bug in my code. It was connected with my tryings of reusing fragment and it's a little bit to complex to post it here.

Comment: @Orest, I am also facing kind of similar issue at my end, can you please by some way help me by explaining what was problem in your case? Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. Was unable to select the first radioButton in the group, but could select the other two. And after selecting the second radioButton, I could select the first one as well. I resolved it by doing a single radioGroup.clearCheck() instead of individual radioButtonA.setChecked(false)

Comment: I used radioGroup.removeAllViews() to remove all view. I also think that all checked item will be clear. But it's not work. 
But radioGroup.clearCheck() works like a charm. Thanks alot

Comment: It's work for me but small issue is occur i change BG(set selector) of radio button on button check  when i set radioGroup.clearCheck()  BG not set as per my selector can yo please tell me what wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [OnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) and make use of the method `setSelected(true)` or `setChecked(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

if u want to uncheck radio button try this method:

```
@Override
public void clear() {

performed.setChecked(false);

nonperformed.setChecked(false);

}
```